# jQuery finding the submit button

Tags: jquery

I'm not being able to find the submit button using parent() or siblings or find() or children or anything else. I have many divisions (for loop) with the same structure [each division has a dymanic name]

This is my code:

Javascript portion:

```
 $('.notempty').keyup(function () { 
    alert($(this).val()); // alerts the value normally

      if ($(this).val().length == 0) {        
        $(this).siblings('.submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      } else {
        $(this).siblings('.submit').removeAttr('disabled');
      }
  });
```

HAML: (note name is a variable)

```
  %div{id: 'status' + name, class: 'modal hide fade padded'}
            %form.form{name: 'form' + name, class: 'form-inline'}
              .form-group
                .col-10
                  %input.form-control{id: 'duration', name: 'duration', class: 'notempty'}
                .col-sm-offset-2.col-sm-10
                  %button.btn.btn-default{type: 'submit', id: 'submit', disabled: 'disabled', class: '.submit'} Submit
```

The code worked when I explicitly use `$("#submit")` but I can't do that with more than one division since it will return the first submit it finds, not the one related to that specific form/divison

Update HTML generated in source view

```
<!-- popup -->
<div class='modal hide fade padded' id='statusx1'>
  <form class='form form-inline' name='maintenancex1'>
    <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='col-10'>
        <input class='form-control notempty' id='duration' name='duration'>
      </div>
      <div class='col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10'>
        <button class='.submit btn btn-default' disabled='disabled' id='submit' type='submit'>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be better if you showed us the actual HTML output that this is generating.

Comment: Yes, as @adeneo stated, please also post the generated HTML.

Comment: Could you also create a jsFiddle for us to work with?

Comment: Is your button class really `class=".submit ..."` (with the dot?)  Try removing the dot from the class name.  eg: `class="submit btn btn-default"`

Comment: yes the dot was my problem aghhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: @fizzix all from experience, unfortunately.  :-)

Comment: @Paul -  Haha. I admit, I've done it before as well. Just get use to that jQuery notation unfortunately.

Comment: thank you all .... I'm losing my eyesight slowly @@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your siblings code is wrong as well though. In jQuery a sibling is a element that is contained within the same parent, not the grandparent element which is the case you have. So an example of siblings in your case,

```
<div class='col-10'>
        <input class='form-control notempty' id='duration' name='duration'>
        <div class='i-am-a-sibling-to-notemptydiv>
</div>

<div class='col-10'>
        <input class='form-control' id='duration' name='duration'>
        <div class='i-am-not-a-sibling-to-notempty'></div>
</div>
```

What you want is to write the javascript portion like this,

```
      if ($(this).val().length == 0) {        
        $(this).parents().find('.submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      } else {
        $(this).parents().find('.submit').removeAttr('disabled');
      }
```

Also, like pointed out earlier, don't write .submit but submit in html class.

Comment: Yeah that too, I ended up using .closest('form')